# If there are n items in *ngFor array, change detection runs n times. Why?

Tags: angular

In following code, `todos` is having 2 items. When button is clicked an additional item is `added` into array.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
      <button (click)="add()">Add</button>
      <div *ngFor="let todo of todos">
          {{todo.title}} - {{runChangeDetection}}
      </div>
  `,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,

  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  todos = [{ title: 'One' }, { title: 'Two' }];

  add() {
    this.todos = [...this.todos, { title: 'Three' }];
  }
  get runChangeDetection() {
    console.log('TodosComponent - Checking the view');
    return true;
  }

}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n1tmif?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**My expectation:**

When user clicks on button a new item is added to `todos` and then changes detection runs. CD realizes that `todos` has been changed and hence rerender the array. This way I am expecting CD to run once.

**Reality**

If there are n items in `todos` array, change detection runs n times (not just 1 as I was expecting).

Can someone provide some insight into CD and explain why is it happening?

Comment: How do you decide how many times CD is run?

Comment: CD is triggered by DOM event handler. If I am clicking the button once, it should be triggered once

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. You said "change detection runs n times". How do you deduce that change detection is run n times? What makes you think it's run n times and not once or twice?

Comment: oh...I am logging it into the console via `runChangeDetection`

Comment: OK. So, if you see "TodosComponent - Checking the view" 6 times in the logs, you deduce that Angular runs 6 change detections? That's not correct arithmetics. If you have three items in your list, since runChangeDetection is called for each of the items, seeing the log 6 times means that there has been 2 change detections (6 / 3 = 2).

Comment: you are right. my way is wrong. I should've use ngDoCheck instead. Thanks!